# How to display information inside modal from url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am very new to js overall so please be patient with me.

I need to make a simple task which is stated in the topic. I have done some research and tried to make using ui.router but since I am not very good with coding something went wrong.

I want that this information from url would be displayed inside the modal dialogue http://prntscr.com/ashi5e

So here is the code:

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.open = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });


    };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/example.js"></script>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h3>Log</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

   Content
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
  </div>
 </script>

 <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Log</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the data (eg. with a service) and put it into $scope.items. In your modal do the same: get items and bind it to your scope. That's all

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log, $http) {

    /* Get data here with a service or smth */
    $scope.items = '';

    $scope.open = function () {
       $http.get("YOUR_URL")
         .then(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                  resolve: {
                     items: function () {
                        return $scope.items;
                  }
                }
             });
         });
    };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
    $scope.items = items; 

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
 <script src="js/example.js"></script>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h3>Log</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{items}}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
  </div>
 </script>

 <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Log</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $scope.items = [{id:1, name:'test'}, {id:2, name:'test2'}];
I know how to do it like this but I need to fetch information from an url.

Comment: Maybe I could use something like $http.get ? I've tried that with Jason, but it's a local file. Where I would like to get the information from a server.

Comment: Yes you are right. Use $http.get and in success open that modal window. :-)

Comment: I have tried that but probably I missed a a step doing that, I thought maybe there will be a kind soul who could implement it in the code I have posted.

Comment: Oh wow :) thx Arun Shinde for supporting. I was for lunch. Approved your edit

Answer (score 0):

You didn't registered `modalDemoCtrl` and `ModalInstanceCtrl` at first you need to register both controller like: `myApp.controller('modalDemoCtrl', ModalDemoCtrl);` where `myApp` is angular module like: `var myApp = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);`.

you can use a service to get data from an url by using`$http` and that service inject in your `modalInstance` controller. in my example create `dataService` and a function named `getData` and called this function from `modalInstance` controller. like: `dataService.getData().then(..` and use then function to get response. and store response data in to `$scope.infos` variable so you can use this `$scope.infos` in your modal.

```
var myApp = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);


var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.open = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });


    };
};
myApp.controller('modalDemoCtrl', ModalDemoCtrl);


myApp.factory('dataService', function($http) {
  return {
    getData: function() {
      return $http.get('http://prnt.sc/ashi5e');
    }
  };
});


var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, dataService) {
    dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
      $scope.infos = response.data;
    });
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};

myApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ModalInstanceCtrl);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that when I go back home. Do I need to do something with the html part?

Comment: html part as it is but need to update to show `infos` in your html and ensure that you have access to get data by url that you provide